# How to extract string inside a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Need a solution for bellow code.

```
variable = ' "value" '
```

How to get `variable = 'value'`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
variable.replace("\"","").strip()
```

`replace` replaces the double quotes with nothing (removes it) and `strip()` removes the trailing and leading spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = ' "value" '

s = s[2:-2]

print(s)
```

Output:

```
value
```